# Mathematical representation of projection plane

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, projective-geometry, parametrization

I've gotten the following assignment, given this specification of a screen I need to project a video onto, I want the video to appear flat.
[image: Projection Screen]

My idea was to find a parametric equation describing this surface and then using some coordinate shifts and interpolation to warp the video accordingly. Since the image is a 2-manifold I know I'm supposed to be able to describe it locally as a coordinate shift, probably will be able to do it with one coordinate system if chosen correctly.
My issue is I'm not too sure how to even approach this,
How would I represent this in mathematical form.
I'm adding another image for 3D feel of it.﻿
[image: 3D drawing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Instead of taking a purely analytical approach, I've decided to put my engineering hat on. Played around with some different equations till I got this $z=y-tx^2$ where $t\in(0,1)$. Of Course this needs finer tuning but this was kind of what I was looking for to get started. Now I can refine my constants using the data, and hopefully all will be well.
[image: Some Trial]